# Htaccess rules for seo-friendly slugs on a site with different languages

Tags: php, html, mysql, .htaccess

My website is about news and I have 3 different languages for my users to choose from: English, Spanish and German.

I managed to fix the .htaccess to work with the english news only, but not the rest of languages, using SEO-friendly urls (slugs) in the following way

Directories:
By default the main page redirects all users to english folder at

```
English: example.com/english/index.php
```

If users choose Spanish or German they just get another folder like this

```
Spanish: example.com/spanish/index.php
```

or if they choose German language they go to the German folder like this

```
German: example.com/german/index.php
```

Now when the users click on the news in the english folder, they get a SEO-friendly URL using slugs stored in MySQL and using .htaccess to go to an address like this

```
example.com/english/worldnews/this-is-a-nice-url
```

The real address is obviously hidden to the user but it is the following address file:

```
example.com/english/news.php
```

Now the code in the .htaccess to make it work is the following code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ english/news.php?article=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ english/news.php?article=$1
```

The problem is that when people is using spanish or german (folders) language they get always redirected to the english news only

```
english/news.php
```

The link slug is comming from MySQL and linked like this

```
<a href="<?php echo $row['seo_link'];?>"><?php echo $row['title'];?></a>
```

In the database the link is stored like this:

```
worldnews/this-is-a-nice-url
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I got an idea, a solution, maybe not the best but I just created sub-domains in the hosting and every sub-domain has its own .htaccess file so I just link the users like this

```
es.example.com
en.example.com
de.example.com
```

they change language and then I just use the same rules just changing the language to each subdomain .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ english/news.php?article=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ english/news.php?article=$1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).